# An integral involving Gaussian hypergeometric function and exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, hypergeometric-function

The integral is

$\int_{0}^{1}x^a (1+x)^b e^{-cx^2}{_2F_1}(-\frac{n}{2},n-1,n-0.5,x)dx$,

where $a$, $b$ and $n$ are positive integers, $c$ is a positive real number.

Is there a closed-form result of this integral, or alternatively an upper bound?

I have tried several methods to obtain an upper bound, mainly by separating $e^{-cx^2}$ and the hypergeometric part (since there is no exisiting result of a integral with both, to best of my knowledge). But the monotonicity of the separated parts can not match.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could consult the following paper where many explicit examples of the style of your integral are treated.

Letac, G. and Piccioni, M. (2012) 'Random continued fractions with beta hypergeometric distribution.'   Ann.  Probab. 40, number  3, 1105-1134.

Comment: Thanks for your paper, but the most difficult part of my integral is the existence of the exponential function, which seems not considered in your paper.

Comment: You are right.  I would try to expand the integrand in a power series